# Plane $U$ in $R^3$ with normal $b$. And matrices $P,B$. Prove $R = 2P - I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Given:** Plane $U$ in $R^3$ with normal $b$. And matrices $P,B$ that $Pb = 0$ , $Rb = -b$ , $Pu = Ru = u$ for every $u \in U$.

> **Prove** $R = 2P - I$

Well, I want to approach this question by first saying that from $Pu = Ru = u$ we know that first $Pu = Ru$, which means $u$ is a base in $R^3$ that makes it true if and only if this base is $e_i$ base in $R^3$. and thus, we can conclude that $Pu = Ru = u$ if and only if $P=R=I$. thus, $Iu = Iu = u$.

We can conclude that $I = 2I - I$.

Well, I didn't use all the given things which makes my solution (maybe) wrong, but I think I've got a point there about how to solve it. What do you guys think?

**Edit:** we can multiply with $b$ both sides of this equation: $R = 2P - I$

and we get $Rb = 2Pb - Ib$, which equals to $ -b = 2*0 - Ib $ , which makes the statement true too.

***NOTE:** I've just re-read the question and it states **"ASSUME YOU CAN'T USE GEOMETRIC MATRICES"** or something like that. I believe it makes my solution not appliable? confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Note that:

from $Pb=0$ and $Pu=u \; \forall u \in U$ we say that $P$ is the orthogonal projection on $U$;

from $Rb=-b$ and $Ru=u\; \forall u \in U$ we say that R is the reflection trough the plane $U$.

Now, if $PX=X'$ and $RX=X''$ , than $X'$ have to be the middle point of $X-X''$: i.e. $ X+X''=2X'$.

Substitute $X'$ and $X''$ and you have the result.

---

If you don't know projections, another way is to start from the fact that any vector $\vec x$ can be decomposed as  a sum of two vectors: one on the line spanned by $\vec b$ and the other on the plane $V$ (do you agree ?), so we have: $\vec x= \alpha \vec b +\vec u$.

And, from the properties of $P$ and $R$ we have:

$$
P( \vec x)=P(\alpha \vec b +\vec u)= \vec u
$$
$$
R( \vec x)=R(\alpha \vec b +\vec u)= -\alpha \vec b+\vec u
$$
So:
$$
\vec x + R(\vec x)=2 \vec u = 2 P( \vec x)
$$
i.e.
$$
(I+R)\vec x=2P\vec x \quad \Rightarrow \quad R \vec x=(2P-I)\vec x \Rightarrow R=2P-I
$$

Comment: We just studied orthogonal/orthonormal/scalar, without projection/reflection, etc..

Comment: They say I need somehow to use the identical matrices theory like I first stated in my solution and to move from there somehow.

Comment: I've added to my answer another solution. It's better for you?

Comment: I don't understand why we can represent $x$ that way.

Comment: because the vector space spanned by $\vec b$ is the orthogonal complement of $U$ ( $\vec b $ is orthogonal to $V$) so you can use the Orthogonal decomposition theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalDecomposition.html

Comment: Will make sure to ask my teacher about that. Thx.